# How do you send data from Kafka streams to clients via Websockets in PlayFramework?

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using the Playframework along with Scala.  I am trying to consume data from Kafka, process the data, and then push the data via websockets to the client.  Unfortunately, I am still relatively a newbie with this technology.

When going over the documentation, they mentioned to create an actor when you want to create websockets.  Code below is from the website. [web socket](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWebSockets#handling-different-types-of-messages)

```
import play.api.libs.json.JsValue
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.streams._

class Controller4 @Inject() (implicit system: ActorSystem, materializer: Materializer) {
  import akka.actor._

  class MyWebSocketActor(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
     import play.api.libs.json.JsValue
     def receive = {
       case msg: JsValue =>
        out ! msg
     }

     // do i include my kafka consumer here???

  }

  object MyWebSocketActor {
    def props(out: ActorRef) = Props(new MyWebSocketActor(out))
  }

  def socket = WebSocket.accept[JsValue, JsValue] { request =>
    ActorFlow.actorRef(out => MyWebSocketActor.props(out))
  }
}
```

My question is, where do I put the Kafka consumer code.  Do I place it inside the actor?  Is this best practice?  The reason I am concerned about putting it the kafka consumer there is that it will block.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Akka Streams + [Reactive Kafka](https://github.com/akka/reactive-kafka) actually makes this pretty easy.  Just wire a Kafka Source to the WebSocket Source to send Kafka messages to a client via the WebSocket.  Here is a complete demo with code:
https://www.jamesward.com/2016/05/25/combining-reactive-streams-heroku-kafka-and-play-framework/